KMongo - Serializing and Deserializing Nested Generic Data class
Have been running into issues with mapping results from mongo into the proper data type while using KMongo and the default Jackson codec:
Example data classes
data class TestDocument<T>(
  val value: T
)

data class Nested(
  val value: String
)

Example of trying to build collection:
val collection = KMongoSync.createClient(clientSettings).getDatabase(dbName).getCollection<TestDocument<Nested>>(collectionName)

I am able to then use this collection to insert and it seems to work just fine, the issue comes from trying to pull documents out of this collection. Rather than being the proper return type of TestDocument<Nested>, it ends up treating the generic as a map instead of mapping it into the correct object type.
Tracing through the code it looks like at some point the generic information is just getting lost, and usually to solve this for other Jackson cases I would just use a TypeReference<T>, but in this case I have not figured out how that could apply here or if there is some other change with the codec I would need to do in order to achieve this.
